# S07E17 of Adventure time, all food is alive. Why and what is a message?

Tags: adventure-time

BMO is making sandwiches for Fin and Jack, saying that it took a lot of time and struggle at black market to find those ingredients. Is this a cannibalism, black/gallows humor joke?

Comment: Well, all food is alive before we kill it. And it's not cannibalism if its not the same animal as the person that's eating it. But yes, its black humor. Like 90% of the humor in A.T.

Comment: alive in a way that has human characteristics @cde

Comment: It is a common joke/explanation that vegetarians "don't eat anything with a face." perhaps this is a riff on that. Ashly Burch (a season 7 writer) is a self-described "pescatarian." I will note for the record, being a meat eater, that I am not particularly down with being served a face myself!

Comment: ohhh, @Yorik you should add that as an answer.